# Why does WebStorm recursively index folders that are using a symlink?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a TypeScript project with roughly this folder structure:

```
/core/backend 
/core/web
/core/dtos
/core/db
```

I would like to share DTOs between client a server:

```
 ~/projects/core
 ln -s $PWD/dtos $PWD/web/src/app/dtos
 ln -s $PWD/dtos $PWD/backend/src/app/dtos
```

This works fine on both my apps. They compile correctly.

**Problem:**

Webstorm seems to be recursively indexing the symlink:

[image]

The container folders look appropriate with no stray links:

```
~/projects/core/backend/src/app $ls -l                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-xr-x   3 jmurphy  staff    96 Apr 11 22:03 bases
drwxr-xr-x  13 jmurphy  staff   416 Apr 12 11:40 controllers
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jmurphy  staff    40 Apr 11 22:03 dtos -> /Users/jmurphy/projects/pienso/core/dtos
drwxr-xr-x   6 jmurphy  staff   192 Apr 11 22:03 injectables
-rw-r--r--   1 jmurphy  staff  6150 Apr 11 22:03 main.ts
drwxr-xr-x   9 jmurphy  staff   288 Apr 12 01:40 models
drwxr-xr-x   3 jmurphy  staff    96 Apr 11 22:03 utils

~/projects/core/backend/src/app $ cd dtos                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
~/projects/core/backend/src/app/dtos $ ls -al                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
drwxr-xr-x  18 jmurphy  staff   576 Apr 12 11:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 jmurphy  staff   448 Apr 12 11:20 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jmurphy  staff  1025 Apr 11 22:03 document.dto.ts
-rw-r--r--   1 jmurphy  staff  2302 Apr 12 11:03 lens.dto.ts
```

How do i prevent WebStorm 2018.1 from recursively indexing symlink folders?

Comment: please create a support ticket, providing a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: When you tag IDEs, you shouldn't tag two at the time, Intellij IDEA and WebStorm are less related than you may think. I'll suggest an edit to you question.

Answer (score 1):

When running a TypeScript project, there seems to be some type of issue if you do not exclude the 'dist' or whichever file you have set to store your compiled assets.

Right Click 'dist' -> 'Mark Directory As' -> Excluded